# What is the difference between adduser and useradd?

Tags: adduser, useradd

What is the difference between the commands `adduser` and `useradd` on Ubuntu?

Comment: Same question [on Super User](http://superuser.com/q/547966/) and [on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/218993/)

Comment: and also on [Unix stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/what-does-adduser-do-that-useradd-doesnt) (quite detailed answer)

Comment: and it is and stays a good, valid question. The issue is not people asking it in respective contexts, it is that this question needs to be asked at all.

Answer (score 544, accepted):

> `useradd` is native binary compiled with the system. But, `adduser` is
> a perl script which uses `useradd` binary in back-end.
>
> `adduser` is more user friendly and interactive than its back-end
> `useradd`. There's no difference in features provided.
>
> also `adduser` is a wrapper for `useradd`.

**Source: [What's the difference between “adduser” and “useradd”?](https://superuser.com/q/547966/221259)**

Comment: useradd with the `-m` option will create the home directory.

Comment: The implimentation isn't that interesting, the semantics are.  Like `adduser(8)` is more userfriendly and creates and set up a user by default the way you expect.  And `useradd(8)` only do what you ask, so do you want a home directory created, you have to tell it to create it for you.

Comment: -1: Does not tell the fundamental difference between the commands: they have different *roles*, one being a low-level tool. The fact that one is a perl script and the other is a binary is irrelevant. Also, there *are* differences in features.

Comment: I have to google this every time... How can I help myself remember which is which?

Comment: @kkhugs to me "adduser" feels the most intuitive because it's a command that sounds like english, while the other does not, semantically. If you remember it as the "most intuitive" of the two, you can also try to remember it as the preferred/easier one.

Comment: Apparently there _is_ some difference.  I have been ensuring various services that do Not need 'system' privileges have _user_ privilege username-s.    Say MySQL or a Wiki - There is no need for a privileged to  run these kinds of services.  _But_ I tried **adduser** and lots user-oriented  _extras_ were made for my '_service_' accounts.  So I deleted them and now I just use **useradd** -- from above: " _only do what you ask_ " (but specified a non-existent home...).

Comment: under Red Hat `/usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd` .. sheesh ...

Comment: @pzkpfw Completely agree. What do I want to do? "Add a user". Remove " a " and you've got `adduser`

Comment: While I agree the name **adduser** reads better, if you look at **useradd** in its wider context alongside the other related utilities, you can see they are all named in a way that actually quite clearly organises their shared purposes: `useradd`, `userdel`, `usermod`, `groupadd`, `groupdel`, `groupmod`.

Answer (score 201):

**Always use `adduser`** (and `deluser` when deleting users) when you're creating new users from the command line. (If you're writing a script, especially if you aim for portability, you might want to use the lowlevel utilities instead – and `adduser`/`deluser` might not be available on all distros, e.g. on SuSE.)

The `useradd`, `userdel` and `usermod` commands are lowlevel utilities which are there for historical reasons, while `adduser/deluser` Do The Right Thing™. (I remember which to use by thinking that `user*` comes after `adduser/deluser` in the alphabet, and therefore is "worse".)

According to the respective manpages (on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin, i.e. a Debian derivative system).

### Manpage for `adduser` says:

(Emphasis added.)

> `adduser` and `addgroup` add users and groups to the system according to command line
>   options and configuration information in `/etc/adduser.conf`. **They are friendlier
>   front ends to the low level tools like `useradd`, `groupadd` and `usermod` programs**,
>   by default  choosing Debian policy conformant UID and GID values, creating a home
>   directory with skeletal configuration, running a custom script, and other features.
>   `adduser` and `addgroup` can be run in one of five modes:

### Manpage for `useradd` says:

> `useradd` is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should
>   usually use `adduser(8)` instead.

See also: [What's the difference between “adduser” and “useradd”?](https://superuser.com/q/547966/221259) (on SuperUser)

Comment: I never can remember which one, so this is my stupid mnemonic if it helps anyone :) "user" rhymes with "loser", and "loser" comes last. Thus: adduser, deluser.

Comment: I actually *disagree* on "*Always user `adduser`*": For automated scripts I'd prefer `useradd` because it's **always there, non-interactive, and not [distro-specific](http://superuser.com/a/547970)**.

Comment: I tried `adduser` on openSUSE, and it's not there.(13.2)

Comment: @cst1992 You're right, I've edited the answer to reflect this. Curiously enough, when I tried `locate adduser` on a SuSE 11 system at work I found that there was an `adduser` manpage, but no binary (and neither a `deluser` manpage nor a command).

Comment: useradd is better if you're a true sys admin. Not being able to use adduser in an autonomous script is a real bummer.

Comment: On Red Hat `/usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd`

Comment: I can't remember so I use `file $(which adduser)` or `file $(which useradd)` to see if it's a script or a binary

Answer (score 25):

`adduser`: add user with full profile and info (pass, quota, permission, etc.)

`useradd`: add user with his name only (if you want to add a temp user with only a name,other info not required)

Comment: +1 and Welcome! I up voted the person who was incapable of explaining their previous down vote.  Keep it up!  Good programmers always rise to the top - (and don't down vote without an explanation).  :)

Answer (score 12):

Another couple of differences, that lead to specific scenarios where useradd might be preferable.

1. In some newer distros, including Ubuntu 14.4, adduser will prompt for information such as password and "gecos" (data for the finger command).  This means it can be less suitable for calling from a script (credit: already mentioned in a comment by Wernight).

   The prompts can be suppressed by passing null arguments:

   ```
    adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" USER
   ```
2. `useradd` allows you to pass multiple additional groups to add a user to by means of the `-G` option.  `adduser` seems to require that you call the command once for each group to add.

Comment: Doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 8):

`adduser` is friendlier in that it sets up the account's home folders and other settings (e.g. automatically loading system stats and notifications on login), whereas `useradd` just creates the user.

Comment: Wrong. useradd can create home directory with -m, set password with -p, create skeleton files with -k, and add user to group(s) with -G.

Comment: @ychaouche Theres a difference between "will create [...]" and "can create [...]".

Comment: Same difference as using a command with default options and using a command with desired options.

Answer (score 7):

Basic difference is "adduser" will create home directory & add skeleton files to that directory where "useradd" wont create any home directory & skeleton files !

## adduser try :

```
Adding user `try' ...
Adding new group `try' (1001) ...
Adding new user `try' (1001) with group `try' ...
Creating home directory `/home/try' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for try
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Full Name []:
        Room Number []:
        Work Phone []:
        Home Phone []:
        Other []:
Is the information correct? [Y/n] y
```

## useradd try1 :

```
# ll /home/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 Oct 26 15:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 root    root    4096 Oct 26 15:47 ../
drwx------  8 ashishk ashishk 4096 Oct 26 15:50 ashishk/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Oct 14 13:02 .ecryptfs/
drwxr-xr-x  2 try     try     4096 Oct 26 15:52 try/
root@chef-workstation:/home/ashishk#
```

Comment: Wrong. See [previous comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd#comment1632851_345988)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest different between using `adduser` and `useradd` is:

- With `adduser` command, the home folder for the user will be created as default.
- With `useradd` command, there is no home folder for the user.

So I suggest you to use `adduser` instead of using `useradd`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll also point out that `adduser` does not always have the `-M` option and also does not respect the `--system` flag which [specifically says](https://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser):

> Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless of the default setting in /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME). You have to specify the -m options if you want a home directory for a system account to be created.

If you're trying to create a system user *without* a home directory then use `useradd --system -M`.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, with useradd you should be more explicit as it doesn't e.g. create a home directory,you should use the -m option or the -p to set a password. Also another main difference is that useradd has different settings from adduser e.g. set a different shell for the user. In most distros useradd sets usr/bin/sh while adduser sets usr/bin/bash

Answer (score -1):

The **adduser** interactive way to creates accounts and pwd with single command. Which can be only found in the Debian family distros.

Both **adduser** & **useradd** do the same functionality; with few differences in favour of adduser.

When creating a user with adduser it will automatically encrypt the user home directory ( with permission of 755 ).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).