# Arrows do not work, all I see is ^[[A ^[[B^ [[C ^[[D

Tags: keyboard

That should be something obvious, but I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

I am using iTerm and logging in to Ubuntu server remotely.

This is what I see when I press arrows:

```
$ ^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D
```

User was added via `useradd` so the home folder is empty. How can I fix arrows?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those arrow keys work if you use an appropriate shell like `bash`.

The $ is a a clear indicator you are not using one of them (otherwise you would, by default, see more than just a $ as a prompt).

You should have done something like this:

```
useradd -u {username} -d /home/{username} -s /bin/bash -p {password}
```

You do not have to recreate the user though; Afterwards you can change the shell (permanently) when logged into the user:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

- There are more shells. If you feel adventurous change [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) to [zsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell)
- Also have a read on useradd and adduser: https://askubuntu.com/a/381646/15811 (you should use adduser)

Comment: Thanks, in fact changing shell to zsh and regenerating configs helped.

Comment: When I have been creating users on Ubuntu, it has always been defaulting to use `bash`. Is that because I used `adduser` rather than `useradd`?

Comment: @kasperd yes. adduser is a script that sets defaults and then calls useradd. See the link I added: "... by default choosing Debian policy conformant UID and GID values, creating a home directory with skeletal configuration." One of those is setting bash as a shell.