# How to change the prompt of a user, so that it shows the current directory?

Tags: home-directory, adduser

I created user '`user11`' in Linux and changed its home directory using the `-d` option but when I login with this user, it shows '`-bash-4.3$`'.

[image: user mod -d screen shot]

I want to know:

1. What is the meaning of '`-bash-4.3`' and why does it happen?
2. Why `user11` prints its working directory '`/root`' and `user12` prints '`/phome/user12`'?
3. How can I change '-bash-4.3' to it's usual meaning (as `user11` or `user12`)?

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged your question `adduser` but you seem to actually be using `useradd`: AFAIK `useradd` (unlike `adduser`) doesn't copy the skeleton files from the `/etc/skel` directory - in particular, it doesn't create a default ~/.bashrc for the new user.

To answer your questions point-by-point:

1. it is the default bash shell prompt, used in the absence of a more customized one that is usually provided by the user's `~/.bashrc` file
2. because you didn't create the home directory for `user11` (and neither `useradd` nor `usermod -d` do that for you)
3. either copy the default `.profile` and `.bashrc` files from `/etc/skel` into the users' home directories, or delete the user(s) and start over using `adduser` instead

See [What is the difference between adduser and useradd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)

Answer (score 0):

Addressing each of your points in turn:

1. `-bash-4.3` is the default prompt for you shell, which is bash. It shows the shell and its version.. The prompt is set by the environment variable `PS1`. See [Bash/Prompt customization](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization).
2. `user11` has a different value of `$PS1` to user12. You can verify this by typing `echo $PS1` for each user.
3. In `~/.bashrc`, for user12, add the line:

   ```
   export PS1="${PWD}> "
   ```

---

#### Where to set PS1

The value of this environment variable can be set in a variety of places. The most common places are `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bashrc`.

From [Setting the PS? Strings Permanently](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/setps.html)

> Johan Kullstam (johan19@idt.net) writes:
>
> The `PS1` string should be set in `.bashrc`. this is because
>   non-interactive bashes go out of their way to unset `PS1`. the bash man
>   page tells how the presence or absence of `PS1` is a good way of knowing
>   whether one is in an interactive vs non-interactive (i.e. script) bash
>   session.
>
> The way I realized this is that `startx` is a bash script. what this
>   means is, `startx` will wipe out your prompt. when you set `PS1` in
>   `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`), login at console, fire up X via `startx`,
>   your `PS1` gets nuked in the process leaving you with the default
>   prompt.
>
> One workaround is to launch `xterm`s and `rxvt`s with the `-ls` option to
>   force them to read `.profile`, but any time a shell is called via a
>   non-interactive shell-script middleman `PS1` is lost. `system(3)` uses `sh -c` which, if sh is `bash`. will kill `PS1`.
>   A better way is to place the `PS1` definition in `.bashrc`. This is read every time bash starts and is
>   where interactive things - e.g. `PS1` should go.
>
> Therefore it should be stressed that `PS1=..blah..` should be in `.bashrc`
>   and not `.profile`.

The bash prompt is an extensive subject, and too broad to discuss fully here. For further bash prompt customisation, see [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Concering your questions...

> 1. What is the meaning of '-bash-4.3' and why the it happens?

It is the shell used and its version.

> 2. why user11 prints it's working directory '/root' and user12 prints '/phome/user12'?

Because user11 does not have a home directory ( `/phome/user11` ) in the filesystem.

> 3. how can i change '-bash-4.3' to it's usual meaning (as user11 or user12)?

Create a home directory `/phome/user11` as specified from `getent`.

What you have done is that you only have altered the information where to find the user homedirectory, but you did not create one.

Creating a new home directory for `user11`

```
cp -a /etc/skel /phome/user11
chown -R user11:1009 /phome/user11
```

Best would be to use `useradd ... -m` to create the user homedirectory automatically.