# How can I add a user and set the password for them at the same time?

Tags: command-line, users

How do I add a user and set their password at the same time?

I tried:

```
useradd user1 -p user@123
```

Where `user1` is their username and `user@123` is their password.

Comment: Dont!  Note: The -p option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing
           the processes. Review `man useradd`

Answer (score 14):

Instead of `useradd`, use the `adduser` command, which automatically runs `passwd` when you call it, unless you use the `--disabled-login` or `--disabled-password` flags.

Sample run:

```
$ sudo adduser pixie
Adding user `pixie' ...
Adding new group `pixie' (1001) ...
Adding new user `pixie' (1001) with group `pixie' ...
Creating home directory `/home/pixie' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password:                             # password does not show
Retype new UNIX password:                            
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for pixie
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] y
```

See: [What is the difference between adduser and useradd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)

Answer (score 4):

`useradd --help` shows that the login name has to be the last parameter. It says also that the password given with `-p` is the encrypted password of the new account which does not seem to be the case in your example.

It's easier to create the user with `useradd user1` and set his password afterwards with `sudo passwd user1`.

Useful options of `useradd` are `-c comment`, `-m` to create his home directory and `-s /bin/bash` to define his shell.

Which would give `sudo useradd -c'new user xy' -m -s /bin/bash user1`.