# What's the difference between the -d and -m options for useradd?

Tags: useradd

When we use `useradd`, what is the difference between `-d` and `-m`? Because the definitions of both sound similar, which is responsible for creating a home directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 2 options are not really similar, but they can work together. If you look at [the manpage of `useradd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/useradd.8.html) you'll find the following:

```
       -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR
           The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the user's login
           directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to BASE_DIR and use that as the
           login directory name. The directory HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be
           created if it is missing.

       -m, --create-home
           Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files and directories
           contained in the skeleton directory (which can be defined with the -k option) will be
           copied to the home directory.

           By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not enabled, no home
           directories are created.
```

The `-d` option is just to set where the home directory of the created user will be but it will not create it if it doesn't exist. While the `-m` option will create the home directory that is set by `-d` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but, the `useradd` command is a low level command, it is usually [recommended](https://askubuntu.com/q/345974/) to use [`adduser`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/adduser.8.html) instead which is a friendlier frontend for the `useradd` command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, actually Im new to linux and currently learning about System administration.

Comment: Not every Linux has `adduser`, e.g. Arch Linux and its derivatives.