# Ubuntu22.04: useradd don't work as expected

Tags: useradd

I setup a factory new ubuntu 22.04.

I run `useradd test1`, there is no home directory created.

I run `useradd -m test2`, there is home directory with `~/.bashrc` and some other environment files. But the bash script doesn't seem to work: [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPj2r.png)

```
root@jenkins-slave02:/home# useradd -m test3
root@jenkins-slave02:/home# su - test3
$
$
$
$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-x--- 2 test3 test3 4096 Jun  7 05:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4096 Jun  7 05:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 test3 test3  220 Jan  6  2022 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 test3 test3 3771 Jan  6  2022 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 test3 test3  807 Jan  6  2022 .profile
$ set
HOME='/home/test3'
IFS='
'
LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
LOGNAME='test3'
MAIL='/var/mail/test3'
OPTIND='1'
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
PPID='4019868'
PS1='$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/home/test3'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
TERM='xterm'
USER='test3'
XDG_DATA_DIRS='/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
_='-la'
snap_bin_path='/snap/bin'
snap_xdg_path='/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
$
$ cd /etc/skel
$ ls
$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Feb 17 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 105 root root 4096 Jun  7 05:15 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  220 Jan  6  2022 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3771 Jan  6  2022 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  807 Jan  6  2022 .profile
$ pwd
/etc/skel
$
```

I don't modify `/etc/skel`, and here is my `useradd -D` [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCv2r.png)

```
root@jenkins-slave02:/home# useradd -D
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/sh
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes
root@jenkins-slave02:/home#
```

I don't know why. Please help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code. And what is that screenshot supposed to show?

Comment: Hello @muru I update the text. I want to say some environment variable don't work. For example `PS1`, there is no shell promt, no keyboard shortcuts like `tab` is act as `\t` not bash complete and so on...

Comment: I find out that the reason is `SHELL=/bin/sh`, not `bash`

Comment: You can set the default value for `SHELL` in `/etc/default/useradd`

Comment: yes, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [What is the difference between adduser and useradd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd).
I realized there is another command `adduser` in ubuntu.

Comment: So I have one more question, How do I use ansible `user` module to hit `adduser` effect?

Comment: The root cause is default shell is `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`. Add `shell: /bin/bash` in ansible  will do.